# Scala Error: not found: value spark_partition_id

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In `spark-shell`, I wasn't having this issue (Line1) when I called Line2.

```
Line1: not found: value spark_partition_id
Line2: val countPerCustomPartition = businessesDataFrameCustomPartition.groupBy(spark_partition_id).count
```

Then when I called `spark-submit`, I got the issue. I hadn't seen this on StackOverflow before, and it ended up being a simple, but not obvious fix.

- Scala 2.11.8
- Spark 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the top of your Scala class:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id
```